# General solution of laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, heat-equation

I want to know that:
 What is the general solution of the (2 and 3 dimentional)Laplace equation $f_{xx}+ f_{yy}=0$ and $f_{xx}+ f_{yy} +f_{zz}=0$?
With many thanks for your help.

Comment: The form of solution depends on the type of boundary conditions you have. [Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplacesEqn.aspx) are few examples you can take a look at.

Answer (score -1):

For $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ , the general solution is $f(x,y)=A(x+iy)+B(x-iy)$ .

For $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=0$ , the general solution is related to the factorized form of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ in $\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: Yes. But, How can we solve the Laplace equation?